# How to mute audio by looping the last second of every x seconds in the video?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

**UPDATE:**

Баяр Гончикжапов and inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63485394/how-to-mute-audio-after-10-seconds-for-2-seconds-with-ffmpeg-filter-volume/), tried:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -af "volume=volume=0:enable ='gte(mod(t\,20)\,15)'" -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 192K output.mp4
```

Post solved, thank you.

**EDIT:**

I tried the following command but I cannot do it.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "loop=loop=3:size=75:start=25" -c:a copy -t 30 output.mp4
```

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Appreciate any help with that.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414641/repeat-last-frame-in-video-using-ffmpeg) ?

Comment: It actually looks a bit similar. I tried the command there but only the last frame is extended. So when looped at a specific time the movement in the video will stop for the duration you set. The extended second just appears as a frozen image. @harrymc

Comment: Any idea how to achieve it?

Comment: Not from me ...

Answer (score 1):

-f concat

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
f="input 4.mkv"
DUR=$(ffprobe -v 0 -show_entries format=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$f")
echo $DUR
DUR=${DUR%.*}
ITS=0
OTS=20
IT2=19
l="list.txt"
echo "ffconcat version 1.0" > $l
while (( $OTS < $DUR )); do
  echo "file '$f'" >> $l
  echo "inpoint $ITS" >> $l
  echo "outpoint $OTS" >> $l
  for i in $(seq 1 5); do
    echo "file '$f'" >> $l
    echo "inpoint $IT2" >> $l
    echo "outpoint $OTS" >> $l
  done
  ITS=$OTS
  ((OTS=$ITS+20))
  ((IT2=$OTS-1))
done
echo "file '$f'" >> $l
echo "inpoint $ITS" >> $l
cat $l
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i $l -y output.mp4
mpv output.mp4
```

powershell script:

```
$f = "input 4.mkv"
$DUR = ffprobe -v 0 -show_entries format=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$f"
$DUR
$ITS = 0
$OTS = 20
$IT2 = 19
$l = "list.txt"
"ffconcat version 1.0" | Out-File -encoding ASCII $l
while ( $OTS -lt $DUR ) {
  $s += "file '$f'
inpoint $ITS
outpoint $OTS
"
  (1..5).foreach{
    $s += "file '$f'
inpoint $IT2
outpoint $OTS
"
  }
  $ITS = $OTS
  $OTS = $ITS + 20
  $IT2 = $OTS - 1
}
$s += "file '$f'
inpoint $ITS
"
$s | Out-File -encoding UTF8 -append $l
Get-Content $l
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i $l -y output.mp4
ffplay output.mp4
```

Comment: Interesting script, thank you so much for your time. I tried the code, I think I need to rewrite it into a script which I'll run on Windows. I even asked chatgpt to convert it to cmd/ps, but it didn't work. Is there an easy way to convert the script into a Windows executable so I can use it everywhere?

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to do this. When I try the script it actually seems to work, it recognizes the input video but ffmpeg produces an output video that doesn't work. I couldn't find the reason for this. I also uploaded a video, could you check and advise me about what to do? @Баяр Гончикжапов 

youtube.com/watch?v=8sK6JWnMzD8

Comment: error `No capable devices found` → scripts have been cleared of hardware encoder

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I tried the new code, but now I'm getting a different error message and also ffmpeg not outputting video. Would you mind having a look at the screenshot or video? 

@Баяр Гончикжапов

Screenshot: imgur.com/a/EWfaYoO 

Video: youtube.com/watch?v=7xoPr5c0iMM

Comment: rename input file to yours: `$f="Çaykur Rizespor - Özet.mkv`

Comment: remove `(1..5).foreach{` and `}` lines

Comment: `$ITS = 0 $OTS = 20 $IT2 = 1`, `file '$f' inpoint $ITS outpoint $IT2`, `file '$f' inpoint $ITS outpoint $OTS`, `$IT2 = $ITS + 1`